# Is is possible to show that pn converges uniformly on [a,b] to f as n→∞?

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

Suppose I say a function $f(x)$ is interpolated on the interval $[a,b]$ by a polynomial $p_n(x)$ whose degree does not exceed $n$. Also suppose further that $f$ is arbitrarily often differentiable on $[a, b]$ and that there exists $M$ such that $|f^{(k)}(x)| ≤ M$ for $k = 0,1,...$ and any $x ∈ [a,b]$.

Then with these assumptions is it possible to show ( without additional hypotheses about the location of interpolation points a≤x0

If anyone could give me any insight it would br great!

Comment: without additional hypotheses about the location of interpolation points a≤x0 <x1 <···<xn ≤b,that pn convergesuniformlyon [a,b] to f as n→∞? (This is missing in the question however it is the title)

Comment: Read about Weierstrass Approximation Theorem.

Comment: @Piquito I don't think that is applicable here. I'm trying to do it without additional hypotheses.

Comment: Then read up on the Runge phenomenon, that precludes uniform convergence without further assumptions.

Comment: Is there no more guidance you can give? I'm just struggling with this question. @LutzL

Comment: Try to use an internet search engine, on the first google page I find https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon and https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2017/11/18/runge-phenomena/